# Device-tree blob (DTB) in a separate partition

Tags: linux, kernel, boot, partition, device-tree

Currently, I have the device-tree blob (DTB) appended to the Linux kernel. I would like to split the DTB from the kernel to an unique partition containing only the DTB similar to the figure 3 of the link below.

https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/dto

I know how to create a new partition but I'm not sure how to proceed next. I have a feeling that I also need to specify the address in the bootcmd but I'm bit confused. Below is my environment:

```
bootcmd=nand read 0x82000000 0x100000 0x400000;bootm 0x82000000
bootdelay=1
baudrate=115200
ethaddr=00:00:23:34:45:66
ipaddr=192.168.1.10
serverip=192.168.1.2
netmask=255.255.255.0
bootfile="uImage"
bootargs=mem=256M console=ttyAMA0,115200 root=/dev/mtdblock3 maxcpus=1 
rootfstype=yaffs ro mtdparts=hinand:512k(boot),512k(env),4M(kernel),80M(rootfs),-(data)
stdin=serial
stdout=serial
stderr=serial
verify=n
ver=U-Boot 2010.06 (Jul 04 2018 - 11:13:16)
```